# Does Lambda provisioned concurrency still keep a Lambda warm after an availability zone failure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Would a function that is already warm due to provisioned concurrency, switch back to a ‘cold start state’ after an AZ failure?

I couldn’t find anything in the AWS Lambda SLA.

Answer (score 1):

If there is an AZ failure then AWS Lambda will automatically route requests away from the impacted AZ.

Provisioned concurrency capacity will be maintained.

Comment: So, in other words AWS would maintain 2x containers ( x  per AZ, where x = provisioned concurrency)?